# Geonode or Geoserver generates a random sld file for geojson layer during upload, how do I change this

Tags: geoserver, geojson, sld, geonode

When I upload a new geojson layer through geonode web interface a random sld file is generated and it becomes the default style for the new layer.

I would like to remove this random behavior and have geonode or geoserver assign a default/predefined sld to all uploads.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**CLARIFICATION:**

The behavior is not completely random. This one below has a "teal" fill but each upload is assigned a different color. The line stroke is always black and the same width.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I guess that you should upload a .sld file together with the GeoJSON file. Do you really mean that the generated SLD is random and can use what ever colors, line widths etc. and not a simple style that is created from the default template?

Comment: @user30184 , I have added further clarification to the questions above. 

"Do you really mean that the generated SLD is random and can use what ever colors, line widths etc. and not a simple style that is created from the default template?"

I didn't mean that, sorry for my lack of technical understanding. I added screens above so you can see what happens. The line stroke is always black and the fill is always a random color. This one is "teal" but each upload is assigned a different color. 

Do you know the name if the file that controls this behavior?